# Construct queries in LINQ-to-Entities in Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm having a hard time creating LINQ-to-Entities query that would fulfill my requirement.

I have two tables: **Booking** and **ProcessStatusLog**

**Booking Table:**

- PNNumber (PK)
- AccountName

**ProcessStatusLog Table:**

- ID (PK)
- PNNumber (FK)
- InsuranceCode
- Status
- UpdatedOn

Here is the sample data for these tables:

Booking Table

```
|----------|----------------|
| PNNumber | Account Name   |
|----------|----------------|
| 11111    | Boston Celtics |
|----------|----------------|
| 22222    | Miami Heat     |
|----------|----------------|
```

ProcessStatusLog Table

```
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| ID   | PNNumber  | InsuranceCode | Status       | UpdatedOn   |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| 1    | 11111     | FIRE          | NEW          | 02/22/2020  |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| 2    | 11111     | FIRE          | FOR REVIEW   | 02/23/2020  |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| 3    | 22222     | FIRE          | NEW          | 02/24/2020  |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| 4    | 22222     | MORTGAGE      | NEW          | 02/25/2020  |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| 5    | 22222     | MORTGAGE      | FOR REVIEW   | 02/26/2020  |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
| 6    | 22222     | FIRE          | CANCELLED    | 02/28/2020  |
|------|-----------|---------------|--------------|-------------|
```

Now, I want to get the latest status for a single PN per Insurance Code.

For example:
I want to get the latest status for PNNumber 11111. The output that I want to get is **"FOR REVIEW".**

And for PNNumber 22222, the required output would be **"FOR REVIEW, CANCELLED"**

How can I write the EF query for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-created database:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().HasKey(b => b.PNNumber);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().HasData(
        new Booking { PNNumber = "11111", AccountName = "Boston Celtics" },
        new Booking { PNNumber = "22222", AccountName = "Miami Heat" });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProcessStatusLog>().HasData(
        new ProcessStatusLog { ID = 1, PNNumber = "11111", InsuranceCode = "FIRE", Status = "NEW", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("22/02/2020") },
        new ProcessStatusLog { ID = 2, PNNumber = "11111", InsuranceCode = "FIRE", Status = "FOR REVIEW", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("23/02/2020") },
        new ProcessStatusLog { ID = 3, PNNumber = "22222", InsuranceCode = "FIRE", Status = "NEW", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("24/02/2020") },
        new ProcessStatusLog { ID = 4, PNNumber = "22222", InsuranceCode = "MORTGAGE", Status = "NEW", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("25/02/2020") },
        new ProcessStatusLog { ID = 5, PNNumber = "22222", InsuranceCode = "MORTGAGE", Status = "FOR REVIEW", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("26/02/2020") },
        new ProcessStatusLog { ID = 6, PNNumber = "22222", InsuranceCode = "FIRE", Status = "CANCELLED", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("28/02/2020") });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Query:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    this.dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

    string givenPNNumber = "22222";

    var filteredLogs = dbContext.ProcessStatusLog
        .Where(log => log.PNNumber == givenPNNumber);

    // Get date of the latest log for each incurance code for eaxh PNNumber.
    var groupedLogs = filteredLogs
        .GroupBy(psl => psl.InsuranceCode)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Code = group.Key,
            LastUpdate = group.Max(g => g.UpdatedOn)
        });

    var result =
        from logs in filteredLogs
        join latestLogs in groupedLogs 
            on logs.InsuranceCode equals latestLogs.Code into joined
        from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where logs.UpdatedOn == j.LastUpdate
        select logs.Status;

    string finalResult = string.Join(',', result.ToList());
    return View();
}
```

As I only used the in-memory Db I do not know how the EF will generate the query but the plan for the query is:

- get the list of logs only for the given `PNNumber`,
- from that filtered list get the list of `InsuranceCode`s for the given `PNNumber` along with the newest date of any log for that `PNNumber` and `InsuranceCode`
- join the results (list of `InsuranceCode`, `UpdatedOn`, `Max(UpdatedOn)`
- from that join select only the rows where `UpdatedOn == Max(UpdatedOn)` (latest entities for all `InsuranceCode`s for the given `PNNumber`)
- select `Status`es
- join them.

Comment: What if I wanted to get the whole row of a Booking based on the latest status of any of insuranceCode?

Example:
*I filtered for "CANCELLED", I will only get the booking row 22222. 
*But if I filtered for "FOR REVIEW", I will get the booking rows 11111 & 22222.

Assuming a new status change has occured:

{ ID = 7, PNNumber = "22222", InsuranceCode = "MORTGAGE", Status = "APPROVED", UpdatedOn = DateTime.Parse("29/02/2020") }

If I filter for "FOR REVIEW" now, I will only get the row of PNNumber 11111 since the latest statuses for 22222 is now CANCELLED & APPROVED.

Comment: That would involve: filtering the log table by `InsuranceCode`, group the second query by `PNNumber`, join 3ed table in the last query and select the result.

Comment: Many thanks to your informative and direct answer. Big help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will directly translate to SQL or you will need to fetch the entire list first, but you should be able to achieve this by using the `[GroupBy][1]` method.

Assuming your `Booking` model has a list of `ProcessStatusLog` objects called `ProcessStatusLogs`, it should look something like this:

```
var result = bookings.GroupBy(
  x => x.Id,
  (_, g) => g.SelectMany(x => x.ProcessStatusLogs)
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn)
             .FirstOrDefault()
);
```